# calculating probability mass function

Tags: probability

Not quite sure how to approach this question - let's say you're looking at a toll booth lane that can hold up to $7$ cars at a time.

$X$ is the $\#$ of cars in the lane at a randomly chosen time 
with the probability $X = x$ proportional to $(x + 1)(8 - x)$.

How do you calculate the probability mass function (pmf) and then the probability that $X$ will be at least $5$? I have absolutely no idea how to calculate for the pmf, but I *think* calculating for $P(X > 5)$ goes like this:

\begin{array}{ll}
P(0) &= (0+1)(8-0) = (1)(8) = 8\\
P(1) &= (1+1)(8-1) = (2)(7) = 14\\
P(2) &= 18\\
P(3) &= 20\\
P(4) &= 20\\
P(5) &= 18\\
P(6) &= 14\\
P(7) &= 8\\
\end{array}
and so
$$
P(X > 5) = P(5)+P(6)+P(7) = 18 + 14 + 8 = 40.
$$
If someone could point me in the right direction, that'd be great.

Comment: probability is strictly defined to be between $0$ and $1$, so it can't be $8$ or $14$.

Answer (score 1):

You have overlooked the word *proportional*.

You don't have $P(0)=8$.  Instead, you know there is a constant $c$ such that $P(0)=8c$.

Similarly, you have $P(1)=14c$, $P(2)=18c$, etc.

Now, use the fact that $P(0)+P(1)+P(2)+...+P(7)=1$ and solve for $c$.  Then you will be able to calculate all values of $P$ exactly.

Comment: I completely forgot the sum of probabilities needs to equal 1....so when I solved for the constant c where the sum of probabilities of all values = 1, c = 1/120. Is this what is considered the pmf value? and then P(X > 5) would be P(5) + P(6) + P(7) = 40c = 40 (1/120) = .0003?

Comment: Your probability mass function is $P(x)=c(x+1)(8-x)$.